# Run playwright in interactive mode in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, chromium, playwright, playwright-python

I was using playwright to scrape pages using Python. I know how to do the same using a script, but I was trying this in an interactive mode.

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect
import time

def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()

    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.wikipedia.org/")

    context.close()
    browser.close()
with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

I tried to do this in interactive mode as:

```
>>> from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect
>>> playwright = sync_playwright()
>>> browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
```

But this gave me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hpoddar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 578, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'PlaywrightContextManager' object has no attribute 'chromium'
```

Comment: with sync_playwright() as playwright:   is not the same as "playwright = sync_playwright()" . playwright object is only valid INSIDE the context manager opened by "with"  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers

Comment: @PmpP. check out Charchit's answer, that's what I exactly needed https://stackoverflow.com/a/73271105/10216112

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `.start()` method:

```
>>> from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect
>>> playwright = sync_playwright().start()
>>> browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
>>> page = browser.new_page()
```

Alternatively, if you just want an interactive browser, and don't care about an interactive shell, you can also use the [`wait_for_timeout`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-timeout) function instead (only applicable on `Page` objects) and set the timeout to a high value:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.wait_for_timeout(10000)
```

Comment: is there any method like `sync_playwright().stop()` ?

Comment: @Himanshuman just do `playwright.stop()`